# QT 5.8 - Cross compiling from Mac target Linux

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt5

I have a QT project that was originally developed for Mac and now we are porting it on Linux.

What I would like to do is to build (and Deploy) the project across both platform (Mac and Linux) **using the Mac**, possibly from QT Creator.

For this reason I need to configure QT Creator (creating a new Kit) adding a Linux Toolchain. I found the appropriate toolchain here:

[Linux tool chain for Mac](http://crossgcc.rts-software.org/doku.php?id=compiling_for_linux)

Unfortunately that toolchain not contains the QT Framework. So I need to cross compile QT from the Mac using the Linux toolchain above.

To cross compile QT I tried this configure parameters (~/gcc-4.8.1-for-linux64/x86_64-pc-linux/ is the Linux toolchain path):

```
./configure -prefix ~/gcc-4.8.1-for-linux64/qt5.5.0 -xplatform linux-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/gcc-4.8.1-for-linux64/x86_64-pc-linux/  -opensource -confirm-license -no-opengl -make libs -make tools -nomake examples -nomake tests  -sysroot ~/gcc-4.8.1-for-linux64/
```

Unfortunately the command miserably fails with this error

> Note: QtSerialBus: Cannot find linux/can.h and linux/can/raw.h Linux headers for socketCAN support.
>
> Note: No wayland-egl support detected. Cross-toolkit compatibility disabled.
>
> WARNING: No QPA platform plugin enabled! This will
>   produce a Qt that cannot run GUI applications.
>   The dependencies needed for xcb to build are listed in
>   src/plugins/platforms/xcb/README
>
> ERROR: detected a std::atomic implementation that fails for function pointers.
>   Please apply the patch corresponding to your Standard Library vendor, found in
>     qtbase/config.tests/common/atomicfptr

Any thought?
Cheers

Comment: The path of least resistance is to just spin up a virtual machine with the other platform and do the build there. Doing that will save you a lot of pain. Cross compiling is more pain than it's worth.